# Case Sensitive GET

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, get

I have an MVC application where I am passing some arguments via GET.  Everything works great but some of the information I am passing I would like to keep the case of.  For example one field I pass is `title`, so `?title=My Title` that works great, except when I get to my controller method the value in the title field of my model is `my title` is there any way I can keep the case calling a controller in this manner?

This is how I am calling the controller in javascript like so:

```
var url = "@(Url.Content("~/Controller/Name/?title=My Title"))";

window.open(url, "_blank");
```

Comment: Is reformatting in the controller out of the question?

Comment: no I guess not, is there a way I can format it as "title case" in the controller? I guess that would suffice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Case sensitive URLs are not a good idea even when not causing SEO issue, its just a bad idea.  I developed a solution where I passed an ID in the URL and queried the necessary data from the DB within my controller.

Comment: Probably a safer alternative!

Comment: that what I thought too.  Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 1):

First make this function...

```
function firstCharsToUpperCase( char ){
  return char[0].toUpperCase();
}
```

Then in your controller you should have access to params or a key/value pair of some sort like this...

```
params['title'] = params['title'].replace(/\b[a-z]/ig, firstCharsToUpperCase);
```

You would then reassign the key title to the new value of "My Title"

Also, params should be case insensitive. Perhaps there is something converting the URI?

Maybe its in the Url.content() function. Can we see what it does?

Also, here is an article regarding case sensitive routes [Never Use Capital Letters](http://wiredimpact.com/blog/never-use-capital-letters-urls/)

**UPDATE**

I found this

> If the specified content path does not start with the tilde (~) character, this method returns contentPath unchanged.

here [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492566(v=vs.118).aspx)

Perhaps what it is saying is that if the '~' is left off, you will get what you give it. Try it out and see?

Comment: Url.Content is a razor function from System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper class check it out if you like. I agree with the article you posted, but I am not handling the URLs differently they aren't part of a path simply values to be sent via Get there would not be 2 different pages for the same URL.  Also your example capitalizes the first letter of every word I wouldn't want words like "a", "the", "to" etc capitalized.

Comment: Ah, then we must find out whey your strings are getting converted.

Comment: it seems when passing values via Get everything is converted to lower case I guess??

Comment: Did you try to remove the "~" or can you?

Comment: I didn't but then I would need to use an absolute path I believe, which is not something I want to do

Comment: Can you just try it out to see if it is in fact Url.content changing your content?

Comment: Seems like it may be better to leave it converting everything to lower as I don't want potentially cause issue else where with URLs not being all lower case.  With the title, one of the arguments I am passing is the unique identifier in the my DB where I can query the other required data in my controller. This will actually make the URL a lot shorter anyway which is probably a good idea.  Thanks for your effort.